# Trace of a third order tensor

Tags: tensors, trace

So, I have learned that the trace of a second order tensor $\textbf{Q}^{(2)}$ is given by:

$Tr(\textbf{Q}^{(2)})=Q_{11}+Q_{22}+Q_{33}$

Now, I want to calculate the trace of a third order tensor $\textbf{Q}^{(3)}$, is it true that:

$Tr(\textbf{Q}^{(3)})=Q_{111}+Q_{222}+Q_{333}$ ?

Or maybe this just doesn't make sense... In particular I want to calculate the trace of:

$Q_{ijk}=\int\bigg[r_{i}r_{j}r_{k}-\frac{1}{5}r^{2}(r_{i}\delta_{jk}+r_{j}\delta_{ik}+r_{k}\delta_{ij})\bigg]\rho(\textbf{r})d^{3}r^{\prime}$

where $\rho(\textbf{r})$ is a function of $r_{i}$, also $i,j,k=1,2,3$ (It is supposed to be a traceless tensor).

Any help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trace generalizes to [tensor contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction) which is defined for *pairs* of indices.

I suspect that by calling $Q$ a "traceless" tensor, the author/ your professor means that contracting $Q$ over any pair of indices yields $0$.  Which certainly *is* the case here (try summing the part in brackets over any two of the indices and then notice that this is a totally symmetric tensor).

Comment: Okay, nice, but what does it mean for rank-4 tensor? What is a trace for a rank-4 tensor?